# How to install UWP package without certificate?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, uwp, certificate

Normally when we download and install an app, we just click install, agree to license, set location and we are done. App gets installed.

Today I exported a UWP app, the release folder contains the install program too, but I can't install it in the same way, I had to run a PowerShell script to install the app or I have to install a 'certificate' manually, then I can install the program. Why?

And this kinda hassle. How can I avoid this? If certificate installation is mandatory then why other program doesn't require this? Are they use any build-in certificate? If so, how can I make something like this? How can I mark myself(/my app) as a trusted publisher/trusted source?

In short form, my question is, how can I make an easy installer?

I'm very new to this, please help me out. I have added my release folder's screenshot. This may help you to understand what am I talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the **Important** part of this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#configure-a-package-with-the-manifest-designer), it mentions

> If you're publishing your app in Microsoft Store, your app will be
> signed with a trusted certificate for you. This allows the user to
> install and run your app without installing the associated app signing
> certificate.

So when you download and install an app from Store, you just need to install the app without installing the certificate.

> If you are installing the app package on your device, you first need
> to trust the package. To trust the package, the certificate must be
> installed on the user's device.

So if you and other users wants to install the package, it is necessary to install the certificate on the device by using PowerShell or manually first and then you can install the package.

Comment: So you are saying that unless I upload the app to ms store, this is the only way to install uwp apps?

Comment: Yeap, although there is more than one way to install apps, you have to install the certificate first.